# How to calculate using time function

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, time

I want to calculate when a building close to a train tunnel construction project will (likely) be exposed to noise. I have set the noise limit in distance based on similar projects, so buildings closer than 200 meters need to be notified, and they need to know 4 weeks in advance. The noise will likely be excessive in a 3D radius around the tunnel boring machine head. How can I calculate which buildings will be affected by noise in a certain time period? It would be great to be able to visualise this using time slider or animation.

I have the following data (see illustration):

- LINE (underneath points): train track line with time data (date, not time, of expected finishing of that train track segment)

  - POINTS (green): the same as the line, just with 1 point for each meter of the train track which is under construction and the planned finishing date of each meter, seen in illustration with date labels
  - POINTS (pink): nearby buildings who might be bothered by the noise of the train track construction
  - POLYGON (blue): 200 meter buffer zone around the train track, which is the distance that the noise is expected to exceed noise limits

I have tried creating 200 meter 3D buffer zones around each tunnel track point (each meter) to see which buildings fall into each buffer sphere, but some buildings are then included in 200 different spheres. Does anyone know of a simpler solution?

I am using ArcGIS 10.3

[image: my data]

Comment: I think your task can be done by a python script (or a model). You should create a table with the building ID, time stamp and a Status attribute, wich is based on 3 classes: less than 4 weeks in advanced, currently exposed by noise and more than 4 weeks in advanced / not exposed. The table can be joined with the building Points and animated by timestamp and symbolized by the Status attribute of the join table.

Comment: Thanks @Saleika. I am not really good with python though, should have included that in my description. Can you or anyone give some pointers as how to do this?